# What does "Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib:..." means?

Tags: iphone, xcode, console, debugging, breakpoints

I get this message on the debugger console, but the application seems work. The full console below.

```
[Session started at 2010-01-05 20:17:29 +0100.]
Warning - No location found for "BGTangramLevel.m:1"
Warning - No location found for "BGTangramClues.m:1080"
Warning - No location found for "BGTanRender.m:143"
Warning - No location found for "compactTangramViewController.m:70"
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1128) (Sat Sep 26 06:46:24 UTC 2009)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
Loading program into debugger…
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Program loaded.
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-1776-28
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
[Switching to thread 11779]
[Switching to thread 11779]
(gdb) continue
warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 5.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 6.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 7.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 8.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 9.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 10.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 11.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 12.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 13.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 14.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 15.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 16.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 17.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 18.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 19.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 20.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 21.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 22.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 23.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 24.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 25.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 26.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 27.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 28.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 29.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 30.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 31.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 32.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 33.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 34.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 35.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 36.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 37.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 38.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 39.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 40.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 41.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 42.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 43.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 44.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 45.

warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 46.

Error in re-setting breakpoint 47:
Error in re-setting breakpoint 48:
Error in re-setting breakpoint 49:
Error in re-setting breakpoint 51:
warning: Couldn't raise load state for requested shlib: "compactTangram" for breakpoint 52.
```

What should I look for? Where should I look for the bug if it's a bug at all?
I also found a warning at the top "No location found for...". What is that means? Seems everything works.

Ideas?

Comment: Anyway, the reported BGTanRender class has been removed earlier from the project, but he cannot fond location for it.

Answer (score 0):

Whohh, found.

There were **some remaining breakpoints from earlier development states**.

I went to Run/Show/Breakpoints then deleted all breakpoint found there, the errors gone.

Comment: Whooo, and now it works with Deployment OS targetet to 2.2.1.
Werid world of iPhone development.